# Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson.2.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I import project from eclipse to android studio, and got above message after Sync project with gradle files. I am new with android studio, don't know how to solve this error.

Following is the Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.s5.selfiemonkey1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/parcelgen.jar')
    compile files('libs/scribe-1.1.2.jar')
}
```

Build Gradle from Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try   `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'`

Comment: not working, I set compile SDK 19.

Comment: for me helped this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33209366/1931613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson's latest version is currently 2.3.1 https://github.com/google/gson/releases

Try with `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'`

Comment: Can you post your base `build.gradle` file?

Comment: sorry, but I am completely unknown with android studio and gradle scripting. Where I can find base build.gradle.

Comment: Should be in your project's base folder

Answer (score 3):

Since GSon is in mavenCentral , you have to add mavenCentral() in buidscripts phase.

Comment: Also one more thing  Found out in project  settings. In projects tab  android plugin repository was set to mavencentral but default library repository was blank, making both same worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the Gson library in the dependency using project structure, now to update the gradle, for the add the .jar file to your build.gradle file like

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
}
```

if it dosent works try changing it to

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

make sure you are also connected to the internet so that jars will be downloaded online through maven repo.