# Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gson

Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1

Show in Project Structure dialog

build.gradle:app

---

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'

  android {

   compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.main"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
compile project(':Uni_Image_Lod_Lib')   }
```

builde.gradle:Project

---

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to  all  sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
  allprojects {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
  }
```

---

step follows:

Android Studio Version 1.3.2

Restart computer

Invalidate caches/Restart

up dawn dependency.

but nothing to change. now what will be the solution for this.

**After Some Changes**

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'

  android {

   compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.main"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile project(':Uni_Image_Lod_Lib')   }
```

and get error rebuild

Unresolved dependencies detected while building project in offline mode. Please disable offline mode and try again.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1.
>        Required by:
>            APP:app:unspecified
>   No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1 available for offline mode.

then i have see in prefrences-> Build, Execution, deployment -> gradle.

project level setting is:

*ticked use local gradle distribution*

global gradle setting:

*offline work is not ticked*

Comment: First of all use buildToolsVersion "23.0.1 and remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0' then clean and gradle your project

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks for fast reply, i do as you suggest but error is same.

Comment: Try changing mavenCentral() to jcenter()

Comment: @Rittel thanks but not solved.

Comment: It seems that you are working offline.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how to online?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

remove `.1` and make it compile

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

`as 2.3.1` is not stable and live yet, that's y its giving your error. also never use `+` while compiling as its not a best practice as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply do following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()  //Add following 
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
         mavenCentral() // Add following
         jcenter()
    }
}
```