# gradle android studio 2.3: failed to resolve 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, gson

i'm facing the gradle error failed to resolve while including gson libraries.

I already checked for similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581327/failed-to-resolve-com-google-code-gsongson2-3-1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439041/failed-to-resolve-com-google-code-gsongson-2-2-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867144/android-studio-gradle-not-recognise-com-google-code-gsongson2-3-1) but none of the solution proposed was suitable to me, i continue receiving the same error.

My build.gradle module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

As suggested in the answers it should be enough jcenter repository, as it is a superset of mavenCentral, i tried also different versions of gson, adding "+" et cetera but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: Isn't gradle giving more information about it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, just states that failed to resolve the library repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using this in your app level build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Comment: Actually in my Android Studio 2.3 at home it works (OSX Environment), tomorrow i'll try again at work (Windows environment). Thanks, i'll let you know. How did you evaluate 2.7 as the version for my sdk version?

Comment: in Android Studio 2.3 it automatically shows warning to update it to 2.7

Comment: For some reason, in my case, adding the third digit of the version made Gradle fail. If I omitted it like in this answer, for example, like `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6'`, things worked out...

Comment: The current version is 2.8.5

Answer (score 5):

Dear Fabio Add like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

see in attached snap
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Tried, with little luck unfortunately...thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Try put this line in the build.gradle (Module:app) inside dependecies:

compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

Here is an example:

[Example project with the gson library added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0F8.png)

Comment: Tried this solution, still not working, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the previous version of library , if still not working then download the .jar library file from [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0) and add it to your project. Also check out the possible solutions over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164633/6478047)

Comment: In windows it's still not working but on OSX solution of @Krishna Meena is working. I guess it's some OS related issue..

Comment: On Windows environment i finally decided to give up and included the jar manually, thanks

Comment: The year is 2018, and it still doesn't work on Windows.